# no such file to load -- rspec/autorun (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3, autotest, rspec2

attempting to use rspec2, rails3, and autotest. When running autotest I get stuck with the following:

```
loading autotest/rails_rspec2
style: RailsRspec2

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...

...bin/rspec:2:in `require': no such file to load -- rspec/autorun (LoadError)
```

Looks like a path issue but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here's the [gist](http://gist.github.com/465528) of my configuration.

Any thoughts on what I can do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the rspec trunk (sometime shortly after beta15). Reverting to 2.0.0.beta.15 solved the problem.